# Group on Datetime and give most frequent string value on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, pandas-groupby

I currently have a dataset with 4 columns. One has TimeStamps and the others have strings which represent electrical meter statuses such as "PRODUCT", "PRODUCTOFF", "HEAT" and so on.

The data is currently in a 10 minute format. I need to get this data hourly and keep the most frequent value. So if I have "PRODUCT, PRODUCT, PRODUCT, WATER, HEAT, WATEROFF" for all those 10m TimeStamps, I want it to show PRODUCT. In the situation where I have 3 strings showing twice or 2 strings showing thrice, it can pick any of them.

I was thinking on organizing the data by frequency and getting the nlargest(1) value but I can't get it to work.

This is what I have:

```
TimeStamp               Meter1       Meter2     Meter3
2019-09-16 12:00:00     OFFWATER    PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 12:10:00     HEAT        PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 12:20:00     FANS        PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 12:30:00     FANS        PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 12:40:00     FANS        PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 12:50:00     FANS        PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 13:00:00     HEAT        PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 13:10:00     HEAT        PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 13:20:00     HEAT        PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 13:30:00     WATER       PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 13:40:00     WATER       PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 13:50:00     PRODUCT     PRODUCT     OFF
```

This is what I need:

```
TimeStamp               Meter1       Meter2     Meter3
2019-09-16 12:00:00     FANS        PRODUCT     OFF
2019-09-16 13:00:00     HEAT        PRODUCT     OFF
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can check `mode` , notice here i slice the 1st value after `mode`, since we may have two values are modes for the group

```
df.groupby(df['TimeStamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')).apply(lambda x : x.mode().iloc[0])
0                       TimeStamp Meter1   Meter2 Meter3
TimeStamp                                               
2019-09-16 12 2019-09-16 12:00:00   FANS  PRODUCT    OFF
2019-09-16 13 2019-09-16 13:00:00   HEAT  PRODUCT    OFF
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Works like a charm and goes off alphabetically on cases where 2 tags show 3 times each within an hour. Thank you so much WeNYoBen